Spring Web App give me Whitelabel Error Page
I created a simple web app project whit Intellij but when i run it my call to localhost:8080/home is not working.
my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.levantesi</groupId>
    <artifactId>JobApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JobApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Job App</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


my application.properties
spring.application.name=JobApp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

my controller
package com.levantesi.JobApp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class JobController {

    @RequestMapping({"/", "home"})
    public String home(){
        System.out.println("in home");
        return "home.jsp";
    }

}


my home.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Telusko Job Portal</title>
    <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
    <style>
        h2 {
            font-size: 16px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 12px;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .bg-clr{
            background-color:#f1faee;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-clr">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand fs-1 fw-medium " href="#">Telusko Job
            Portal Web App</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="viewalljobs">All
                    Jobs</a></li>

                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"
                                        href="https://telusko.com/">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Card 1 -->
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-5">
            <div class="card bg-warning">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title">View AllJobs</h5>
                    <form action="/viewalljobs" method="get">
                        <!-- Add your form fields here -->
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Card 2 -->
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-5">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Add Job</h5>
                    <form action="/addjob" method="get">
                        <!-- Your form fields go here if needed -->

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>


<!-- Add the Bootstrap JS and Popper.js scripts -->
<script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

i created a folder under webapp to store all my jsp that's why i used the prefix in the application.properties
i have no error and the console print the "in home" message so the method is called but i don't understand why is not working.
tell me if you need more information about my project.
Thanks
i tryed to run my project but the home.jsp is not working and i get the Whitelabel Error Page
